# Customize dropdown (Picker) list in xamarin.forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, dropdown, picker

I am working on xamarin.forms. I am creating an app for android. In app I have a dropdown list. I am using Picker for it. I customized it to look like dropdown. Now I need to make the first Index item to nonselactable. Means user can not select the first item. If user click on it nothing should happen. But currently when user click on the first index dropdown gets collapsed.

One more thing that I have to add in dropdown is a Cross button at index 1. Means at index 1, on left side there will be Cross button and at center there will be text like Select item. And this whole row should not be selctable. If user click at cross button dropdown should collapsed.

Anyone have idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use listview for dropdown and control its visibility as per need.I faced similar situation where I customized list view to enact dropdown.There is another thing I want to know about Picker.Does your picker accepts or adds string only or you could customize it to accept views or controls?